# Best practice for the R here package (without RStudio)

Tags: r, path, project

I am struggling a bit to understand the best way to use the `here()` package in R. I do not use RStudio and most the examples I have found so far assume the use of RStudio projects.

My organization is simple:

```
project_dir
  |
  |___ data_dir
  |
  |___ scripts_dir
```

If I execute a script located in `project_dir/src_dir` the default R working directory is  `project_dir/scripts_dir/`. The root directory should be `project_dir/`.

The following three scripts work if run with `Rscript`, but seems to need a `.here` file in `project_dir` if sourced from R.

```
# script 1
library(here)
here()
df1 <- read.csv(here("data_dir", "file.csv"))
```

```
# script 2
library(here)
df1 <- read.csv(here("data_dir", "file.csv"))
```

```
# script 3
here::here()
library(here)
df1 <- read.csv(here("data_dir", "file.csv"))
```

In some examples of how to use this library, I have seen the following usage which however doesn't seem to work on my setup.

```
# script 4
here::i_am("src/load.r")
library(here)
df1 <- read.csv(here("data_dir", "file.csv"))
```

My questions are:

1. what are the recommended best practices to use this package when not using RStudio projects? As in script 1, 2, 3? Is there even a difference?
2. What is the role of the `.here` file? Is it needed always or does it depend on how the package is called?
3. When is the i_am() function useful? It seems to me it is not needed to set the project directory, but maybe I am using it the wrong way.

Comment: (1) “Best practices” around this are unfortunately quite subjective. Arguably R does not *have* good best practices. (2) ‘here’ fundamentally uses a heuristic because R lacks proper tools to identify code paths outside packages. A fundamentally better approach would be to use a proper module system, i.e. [‘box’](https://klmr.me/box/). (3) As noted, ‘here’ uses heuristics. Both the `.here` file and `here::i_am()` are crutches to make these heuristics work in a few more circumstances when they invariably fail.

Comment: (Full disclosure: ‘box’ is my project so I am inherently biased. That said, it is based on my decades of experience and research of the best practices for module systems in other programming languages and represents the most comprehensive approach to implement these best practices in R.)